# Confluent:Topic was not created after loading a Connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I tried connecting to several databases including MySQL and MSSQL and i had no problem.

But when i tried to connect to a certain remote MySQL database (That can be accesses only from my company's network) which contains a view that has almost 3 million records, the Connector was loaded and the Status said it's running but there wasn't any topic created to consume the data from it.

What could be the reason? and where can i find the correct log file to know what happened?

[image: Connector Status]

[image: Available Topics]

Here is an example of what the connector looks like:

```
{
  "name": "mysql-source",
   "config": {
   "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
   "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
   "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
   "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
   "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
   "incrementing.column.name": "Id",
   "tasks.max": "1",
   "table.types": "VIEW",
   "table.whitelist": "ticket_rep",
   "mode": "incrementing",
   "topic.prefix": "mysql-",
   "name": "mysql-source",
   "validate.non.null": "false",
   "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://XX.XXX.XX.XX:3306/database? 
    user=user&password=password"
 }

}
```

These are the log results when i run confluent log connect:

```
> [2018-09-11 16:37:57,382] ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='foo', query='null', topicPrefix='mysql-', timestampColumn='null', incrementingColumn='id'}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:247)
java.sql.SQLException: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:975)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.executeQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:201)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:84)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:55)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:179)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2018-09-11 16:38:02,523] ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='foo', query='null', topicPrefix='mysql-', timestampColumn='null', incrementingColumn='id'}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:247)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (7,562,612 > 4,194,304). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:107)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:975)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.executeQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:201)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:84)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:55)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:179)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the table on MySQL is not empty?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous yes it's a view that contains almost 3 million rows

Comment: Can you post your connector's configuration then? Please share the code and not a screenshot.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous i posted it. it's also worth mentioning that this database can only be accessed in a certain network (my company's network)

Comment: I assume that Kafka machine is on the same network right?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous by "Kafka machine" you mean the machine that i'm using Confluent on to connect to the database? if yes then yeah it's my PC which is directly connected to the network, i even tried to load the connector to the database outside the network and it failed

Comment: For how long did you wait the connector to fetch data from your view? Maybe this is a performance issue and it might take too long to load the view with 3M records?

Comment: i waited for about 5 minutes and the topic was still not created, how long should i wait for?

Comment: Have you checked Kafka Connect logs?

Comment: Also, is this your first time trying to run this connector or did you run it before and it was OK?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Yes this is my first time to try connecting to a large table/view.
Alright so i used the confluent log connect command and here are the results:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501054452282

Comment: Post the logs in your question and not as a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large` is a problem on MySQL side which can be fixed by increasing the value of `max_allowed_packet` variable. To do so, you need to include

```
max_allowed_packet=512M
```

under `my.cnf` (or `my.ini`, depending on the OS you are running) file(within `[mysqld]` section) and then restart MySQL. After restarting MySQL,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

should return the value you've set in your MySQL config file.For more details regarding this error you can refer to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html). 



`java.sql.SQLException: Java heap space`, indicates that Kafka connect is running out of heap space. It is possible to control starting and max heap size by running

```
KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1g" connect-standalone connect-worker.properties mysql-source-connector.properties
```

that sets a starting heap size of 512 MB and a maximum size of 1 GB. You might need to change the sizes, according to your needs.

Comment: i did everything and the "Java Heap Space" error still shows up.

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
the result is : 536870912

Comment: @MahmoudElbably See my updated answer and let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't seem to understand where i should run this command?

Comment: How did you run Kafka Connect before?

Comment: `/root/confluent-4.0.0/bin/confluent start `       


then 


`/root/confluent-4.0.0/bin/confluent load mysql-source -d /root/mysql-source.json`

Comment: You can run Kafka connect using the command I have posted in my answer so that you will be able to assign heap size. You can find more details here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#running-workers

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem! much appreciated.

Comment: In the latest Connect code, I think default max heap is 2g